# Which algorithm to use to solve large sparse system of linear equations

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I need to solve a system of linear equations, `AX=B` where `A` has the size of `200000 * 200000`, and `B` has the size of `200000 * 300`.   `A` is very sparse, but `B` is dense.  Also, `A` is symmetric.

In such a situation, what is the best algorithm to use?  And is there any library I can use in python?

So far, I tried `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`, but it took so long that I had to kill it.

Note that I do have access to GPU, so any methods that rely on GPU are welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: The algorithm piece may also be a good question for [math.se] stack exchange

Comment: @G.Anderson There are a bunch of well-answered question on this topic at [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), and it is pretty much off-topic on Mathematics SE.